# unexpected indent error in python 3 i tried fix the spaces bot not work

Tags: python

I have a problem and can't solve it. I have unexpected indent error and I try to fix the spaces and tabs, but the result wasn't changed.

[image]

```
#this file for import data from exceil sheet to sqlite database

import sqlite3
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import re
class Database:
    def slugify(text, lower=1):
        if lower == 1:
            text = text.strip().lower()
        text = re.sub(r'[^\w _-]+', '', text)
        text = re.sub(r'[- ]+', '_', text)
        return text
    #Replace with a database name
    con = sqlite3.connect('warehouse.db')
    #replace with the complete path to youe excel workbook
    wb = load_workbook(filename=r'warehouse.xlsx')
    sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()
    for sheet in sheets:
        ws = wb[sheet] 
        columns= []
        query = 'CREATE TABLE '+ str(slugify(sheet))+'(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT'
            for row in list(ws.rows)[0]:
            query+=','+slugify(row.value)+'TEXT'
            columns.append(slugify(row.value))
        query += ', location Text);'
        con.execute(query)
        tup = []
        for i, rows in enumerate(ws):
            tuprow = []
            if i == 0:
                continue
            for row in rows:
                tuprow.append(str(row.value).strip()) if str(row.value).strip() != 'None' else tuprow.append('')
            tup.append(tuple(tuprow))
        insQuery1 = 'INSERT INTO ' + str(slugify(sheet)) + '('
        insQuery2 = ''
        for col in columns:
            insQuery1 += col + ', '
            insQuery2 += '?, '
        insQuery1 = insQuery1[:-2] + ') VALUES('
        insQuery2 = insQuery2[:-2] + ')'
        insQuery = insQuery1 + insQuery2
# to execute 
#con.executemany(insQuery, tup)
#con.commit()
#con.close()
```

Comment: The line `for row in list(ws.rows)[0]:` should not be dedented by one level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for row in list(ws.rows)[0]:
```

should be indented back 4 spaces.

Comment: thanks Lenik , its very simply